# Trouble downloading selenium Windows 10

Tags: ruby, selenium

When downloading selenium via Ruby's "command prompt" on windows, I ran into the following error after  `gem install selenium`. The script prompted me to run `selenium install` however when I ran selenium, I received the following error:
[image: running]

Any solutions?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. This includes error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Selenium WebDriver for Ruby

Step 1. visit the Ruby site "https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/" and choose one of the installation methods on the site depending on your OS and preferences.

Step 2: verify installation with the command below.

```
C:\>ruby --version
```

If Ruby was installed correctly, you will see the version information as shown below

> ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x64-mingw32]

In this example above, I installed Ruby 64 bit on Windows. During the installation you need to make sure Ruby installer updates some environment path to include Ruby and Gem executable file.

Assuming that you have already installed Ruby on your machine. Let's now install the Ruby WebDriver gem file.

Open command prompt on your operating system and execute the command below:

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
```

Ruby and Selenium web driver is now ready for developing test automation.

for more infortaion use [this](http://davehaeffner.com/selenium-guidebook/install/ruby/windows/1.9/) link.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install selenium webdriver gem.

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
```

Selenium gem is oldest g,em with version (0.2.11) last updated in 2013.

Comment: I did that. Should I still try to run `selenium install` after that? The error remains

Comment: you just need `gem install selenium-webdriver`, don't have to `gem install selenium`.

Comment: I realized that although selenium-webdriver worked, I had to manually install a chrome webdriver. Thank you for the help